# iOS : How to know when device language got changed?

Tags: ios

I'm wondering if there is any callback or another way to know that when device language is getting changed. I need to inform the remote server that user has changed their device language.
I can't notice the change until I start the app again. I need to know the change in device language as soon as possible. The reason behind this is that until I inform the remote server about the language change I may get any push notification in the wrong language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forcing a language change notification iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324589/forcing-a-language-change-notification-ios)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but what you're looking for is `NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification`. Register for this on app launch. Also, check in both `didBecomeActive` and `didEnterForeground` for `locale` changes.

Comment: use with the help of `NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification`

Comment: When we change the device language iOS removes all the apps from memory and it restarts. So will I get informed after restart?

Answer (score 3):

When the device language is changed, all apps are killed. So a simple way to check for a language change would be to store the current language code in `UserDefaults` in`applicationDidEnterBackground(:)`, and then check that value against the current language code in `application(:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`

Comment: @Shubham You won't be able to know about a language change until your app is restarted. There's nothing you can do about that. I'd say it's a real edge case though - how many people actually change their device language (apart from devs when testing)?

Comment: Thanks for the information. And you are right about this case, in general, we rarely change the device language.